# Makefile always running python targets

Tags: python, makefile, data-science

I am attempting to automate a data science workflow using Make, and it is not running the way I would expect it to run. Naturally, I believe there is something wrong with my understanding of Make commands, so I am asking the experts for help.

I have read through the following two similar stack overflow posts, but neither have helped.

[Makefile always running target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289026/makefile-always-running-target)

[Why a makefile target is always run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740853/why-a-makefile-target-is-always-run)

My folder contains the following files:

- Makefile
- sql_statements.py
- pull_data.py
- run_model.py

The contents of my Makefile are:

```
pull_data: sql_statements.py
    python pull_data.py

run_model: pull_data
    python run_model.py
```

When I run `make run_model`, `python pull_data.py` is run and then `python run_model.py` is run. This is expected.

However then I run `make run_model` again, `python pull_data.py` is run and then `python run_model.py` is run again.

The expected behavior is that Make will realize `pull_data.py` and `sql_statements.py` have not changed, and therefore will not run `pull_data.py`. However, if I have changed any of the code contained in `sql_statements.py` or `pull_data.py`, then `pull_data.py` would be run.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Make works by comparing the timestamps of the target with the timestamps of the prerequisites.  If the mod time of the target is OLDER than any of the prerequisites (and, a target that doesn't exist is "infinitely old" of course) then the recipe is run.

The recipe is intended to do some set of commands that create the target and modify its modification time, so that now it's newer than the prerequisites.

So this rule:

```
pull_data: sql_statements.py
        python pull_data.py
```

says "if you need to build a file named `pull_data` and its modification time is older than the mod time of `sql_statements.py`, then run the recipe command `python pull_data.py`".

Since the python command never creates or updates a file named `pull_data`, the next time make runs it will execute the same command again.

Comment: Hi @MadScientist - thanks again for helping me out.

"The recipe is intended to do some set of commands that create the target and modify its modification time" - Maybe this is the gap in my knowledge. I am not attempting to use Make to create the files `pull_data.py` or `run_model.py`... Those files contain code that I have already written.

But shouldn't make still update the modification time for these files, so that it knows whether or not they need to be run? Why is that not happening?

Comment: Adding another comment to address my last question... It appears make does not update the timestamp of the file. I need to include code in the command to update the file's timestamp. Similar to `touch` in linux, but for windows.

Comment: Make never updates any timestamps on its own.  Your recipes must do that.  Normally (for example when you create a file) the operating system will modify the timestamp for you.  If your recipe doesn't create the target file, then you have to do it yourself, by hand.  Make will never do it: it can't know when you want it to be done!  some recipes purposefully _don't_ update the timestamp: for example they may do some other kind of check and see that the file doesn't need to be updated, and not change the timestamp.

Comment: But you have a fundamental mistake by talking about `pull_data.py`.  Make knows **nothing** about `pull_data.py` in your makefile.  You have listed a target of `pull_data` (which is not `pull_data.py`) and a prerequisite of `sql_statements.py`.  Those are the only files make knows about.  The fact that your recipe command references some file named `pull_data.py` is not something make does or can know about.  make takes the text of the recipe and runs it as a shell script.  Make has no idea what it does, what files it accesses, or whatever.  it's a black box to make.

Answer (score 0):

Editing my Makefile to the below appears to result in the behavior I am expecting.

```
pull_data.py: sql_statements.py
    python pull_data.py 
    touch pull_data.py -m 

run_model.py: pull_data.py
    python run_model.py 
    touch run_model.py -m
```

Comment: The problem we have answering your question is, what does the command `python pull_data.py` actually _do_.  You never actually explained that in your question.  Usually a recipe will work with some input files and generate some output file.  If your command updates some file, then that file should be the target of the recipe.  It's very unusual to list the command you run as the target of the recipe, unless somehow it updates itself.

Comment: `sql_statements.py` has three SQL statements stores as strings.

`python pull_data.py` imports each SQL statement from `sql_statements.py`, creates a database connection, pulls the data as a pandas dataframe, then stores the data as a csv in another folder. There are three csv's that get created this way. So rather than call `make csv1`, `make csv2`, and `make csv3`, I thought it would be more straightforward to just run `pull_data.py`, and have that do everything.

Comment: I guess what I've been trying to do is break my code into executable chunks. Make seems the be a good way to do this, and to avoid rerunning things that don't need to be run.

Rather than write a Make statement for each individual operation in my entire codebase, I wrote separate scripts to do a set of related tasks, and I wanted to use Make to execute those scripts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's fine, but make works on files, and comparing their timestamps.  So when you break your work into chunks you have to find a way to represent which chunks are complete and which are not, with files.  So after you finish the first chunk it must result in a file being created on the disk, with an updated modification time.  Etc.  Most of the time incremental work on computers involves updating files like that so make works naturally.  In situations where incremental work does **not** result in files being created, you'll have to mimic that yourself (say with `touch`).

Comment: In your example, you are creating the files `csv1`, `csv2`, and `csv3`.  So _those_ are the output files that specify when the work is complete, and so those should be the targets in your makefile.  The problem is that since you're retrieving those files from a database, there is no prerequisite file that can tell you when those files are out of date because the "prerequisites" are actually the content of a database not a file.  How do you know when you need to recreate `csv1`?

Answer (score 0):

What you likely want to do is something like this:

```
run_model: .run_model

.pull_data: sql_statements.py pull_data.py
    python pull_data.py
    touch $@

.run_model: .pull_data
    python run_model.py
    touch $@

.PHONY: run_model
```

This creates marker files to mark which scripts were run and when (when is recorded in the timestamps).  Ideally, you would rename `.pull_data` and `.run_model` to be the names of the artifacts generated by `pull_data.py` and `run_model.py` respectively.

Also note that `$@` expands to the target's name -- this is a considered cleaner than manually repeating the target name in the recipe.